# How to use the Match Redirect module

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm trying to use the [Match redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect) and follow the basic description I've tried the following:

```
/my-path-1/my-path-2/*
```

to

```
/my-path-2/*
```

OR

```
/ma-path-2/
```

And it doesn't work. I do have pages like:

```
www.example.com/ma-path-2/page-title
```

that works fine as expected, but when I visit

```
www.example.com/my-path-1/my-path-2/page-title
```

I was expecting to be redirected to:

```
www.example.com/my-path-2/page-title
```

Which did not happen. Why? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the module description, I get the impression that the Match redirect module module only replaces wildcards and cannot remove them.

I suggest you try [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module with [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). After you change the path in pathauto, remember to use the BULK UPDATE tab to update the urls. Redirect will automatically do it's thing.

Comment: But the reason I was looking into Match Redirect was that I could batch change those. Your recommendation seems to be for me to change each of of those individually. Am I correct? or is there a way to batch change all pages under `/my-path-1/my-path-2/` to `/my=path-2/`?

Comment: Using Pathauto bulk update will batch them for you. As redirect will auto add them.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I do want to keep both paths as in: `/my-path-1/my-path-2/page-title` AND `/my-path-2/page-title` for about 800 odd pages. How can I use Pathauto for that?

Comment: pathauto + redirect. Backup your db, try my answer, and get back to me.